# Designing the output on the console Java

Tags: java, console

I am making a solitaire game for console only. I have a problem displaying the list into something like this:

[image]

I saw someone do it in C++, that's the picture above. Is there way to do it in Java?

This is my code so far:

```
final String[] cards = {
        "2C", "2D", "2H", "2S",
        "3C", "3D", "3H", "3S",
        "4C", "4D", "4H", "4S",
        "5C", "5D", "5H", "5S",
        "6C", "6D", "6H", "6S",
        "7C", "7D", "7H", "7S",
        "8C", "8D", "8H", "8S",
        "9C", "9D", "9H", "9S",
        "10C", "10D", "10H", "10S",
        "JC", "JD", "JH", "JS",
        "QC", "QD", "QH", "QS",
        "KC", "KD", "KH", "KS",
        "AC", "AD", "AH", "AS"};

int i = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
    int e = r;
    for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
        if (e != 0) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%5s", " "));
            e--;
        } else {
            System.out.print(String.format("%5s", cards[i]));
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

The problem is that I need to add some empty Strings to get this kind of output. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes; have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes.. please look at my post I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a 2D array for your board because it is a better representation of it and thus more easily manipulated. Then I would have a method which is responsible for displaying the array in the console, which will be called whenever an update is needed:

```
public class Example {

    static String[][] board;

    static void display() {

        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String card : row) {
                System.out.print(card + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        board = new String[][] {
            { " 1C", " 2C", " 3C", " 4C", " 5C", " 6C", " 7C" },
            { "   ", " 1H", "10H", " AC", " 5C", " 6C", "10D" },
            { "   ", "   ", "10H", " AC", " 5C", " 6C", "10D" },
            { "   ", "   ", "   ", " AC", " 5C", " 6C", " QS" },
            { "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", " 5C", " 6C", " KS" },
            { "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", " 6C", " AS" },
            { "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "10D" }};

        display();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 1C      2C      3C      4C      5C      6C      7C 
         1H     10H      AC      5C      6C     10D 
                10H      AC      5C      6C     10D 
                         AC      5C      6C      QS 
                                 5C      6C      KS 
                                         6C      AS 
                                                10D
```

Note that some cards are 2 characters long and some are 3. In order to align the output properly, I made all cards 3 characters long with a leading space. As for the space between the columns, I chose a tab (`\t`), but you can replace it with a string of your choice.

Note: when iterating over an array, using a *for-each* loop or limiting to `array.length` is preferable to hard-coding the number.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be ok?

```
final static String[] cards = {
    "2C", "2D", "2H", "2S",
    "3C", "3D", "3H", "3S",
    "4C", "4D", "4H", "4S",
    "5C", "5D", "5H", "5S",
    "6C", "6D", "6H", "6S",
    "7C", "7D", "7H", "7S",
    "8C", "8D", "8H", "8S",
    "9C", "9D", "9H", "9S",
    "10C", "10D", "10H", "10S",
    "JC", "JD", "JH", "JS",
    "QC", "QD", "QH", "QS",
    "KC", "KD", "KH", "KS",
    "AC", "AD", "AH", "AS"};

final static String space = "                                                                     ";

    int i = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
        System.out.print(space.substring(0,r*5));
        for (int c = r; c < 7; c++) {
           System.out.print(String.format("%5s", cards[i]));
           i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Granted, you're still adding strings to the output but it is faster and looks nicer.